# Greenplum vs. mysql performance comparison

Tags: greenplum

I tested the data analysis performance of Greenplum and mysql under the same hardware conditions. Under the condition of less than 10 million data, there was no obvious difference between them. Greenplum had 1 master on 1 node and 4 segments distributed on 2 nodes, which was different from what I expected,Is that normal?

Comment: Why would you want a distributed MPP database for a small table like that?

Comment: thx，I feel that MPP Database has more computing power than a single-node database, and complex aggregation functions for a small amount of data are also time consuming, but Greenplum does not reflect its advantages

Comment: A MPP database scales out - if you want to compare performance on a single system, use PostgreSQL instead of Greenplum.

Comment: I want use Greenplum for complex aggregation functions,so I test Greenplum vs mysql,but it do not work like what I expected